# Table Across Average based on First String Value

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a way to calculate the average across a table based on only the value in the first column (School Name) when the first column is a string value? The current values in School Average are not correct due to the additional column values (Grade and Teacher) needed prior to the measures.[image]

Comment: Instead of screenshot can you post some data to understand the problem clearly.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ideal use case for LOD calculations. An LOD calculation allows you to specify the dimensions for a calculation as part of the calculation definition -- instead of (solely) by the Tableau shelves and cards.

To start, you can define a calculated field called,say, School_Avg as

> { fixed [School Name] : avg([Grade]) }

Assuming you have a field called Grade.

There is much more to learn about LOD calculations. See the on line help to learn more.